# OpenCL - How can my array be too big to cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I'm new to OpenCL and I'm using the C++ wrapper to program with it. I have an older AMD card (Radeon HD 5770) which might be the cause of the problem but I want to rule this one out for now.

I'm trying to "process" an "image" for which I'm faking a 400 x 400 pixel^2 as a 1D array of integers. So, my buffer size should be 4 * 400 * 400 - roughly 640kb. I don't think this is large at all.

Some stats I think are relevant:

- Max work items per work group: 256
- Max Work item dimensions per work group: (256, 256, 256) where x * y * z <= 256, though, I think.
- Max memory allocation size: 536,870,912 (looks like 1/2 GB)
- Catalyst 14.12
- AMD SDK 3.0.0 (Beta)
- Using Visual Studio Community 2013

Some code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>

#include <CL/cl.hpp>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;
#define IMG_WIDTH 400
#define IMG_HEIGHT 400

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);

    cl::Platform default_platform = all_platforms[0];

    vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
    default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
    cl::Device default_device = all_devices[0];     

    cl::Context context({ default_device });

    std::ifstream file("kernels.cl");
    std::string kcode(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
                      (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    cl::Program::Sources sources(1,
         std::make_pair(kcode.c_str(), kcode.length() + 1));

    cl::Program program(context, sources);

    if (program.build({ default_device }) != CL_SUCCESS){
        cout << "Error building " << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device) << endl;
    exit(1);
    }

    int h_C[IMG_WIDTH * IMG_HEIGHT]; // initialize the array.
    cl::Buffer d_C(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * IMG_WIDTH * IMG_HEIGHT); // create the device memory for this array.

    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE);

    cl::Kernel kernel_to_run(program, "get_row");   
    kernel_to_run.setArg(0, d_C);
    kernel_to_run.setArg(1, IMG_WIDTH);
    kernel_to_run.setArg(2, IMG_HEIGHT);

    cl::Event evt;
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_to_run, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT), cl::NDRange(10, 10), NULL, &evt);
    queue.finish();

    /* I think the problem is here. If I comment it out, the program
       will run fine, but I need the device information back to the
       host, though!
    */
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(d_C, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * IMG_WIDTH * IMG_HEIGHT, h_C);

    unsigned long elapsed = (unsigned long)(evt.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>() -
    evt.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>());
std::cout << " result: " << elapsed / (float)10e6 << " ms";

    queue.flush();
    queue.finish();
    delete &d_C;
}
```

The Kernel, which does nothing but only store which global row each "pixel" belongs to:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable
__kernel void get_row(__global int *out, int width, int height){

    int r = get_global_id(1);
    int c = get_global_id(0);

    if ((r >= height) || (c >= width))
        return; 

    int gIdx = r * width + c;

    out[gIdx] = r;

}
```

What am I doing wrong? For 400 x 400, the program gives me an error "Process is Terminated Due To Stack Overflow Exception"

- Are my "image" dimensions too big (a mere 400 x 400) for total work item size?
- I chose a work group size of 100 (10 x 10), so, I think I will have 1600 work groups with a 400 x 400. I don't think there is a limit on the number of work groups, even for older devices, or is there?
- Maybe I don't have my host code in the correct order.

Any help on this is appreciated. I don't want to get a new graphics card if at all possible. I don't want to split my image into smaller rectangles and then divide those up into work groups.

I do the equivalent of the above in CUDA (in another machine) with larger images than 400 x 400 with no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your variable `h_C` consumes a lot of stack memory. Stack memory is very limited. Instead of using a stack variable like,

```
int h_C[IMG_WIDTH * IMG_HEIGHT];
```

Dynamically-allocate it using something like `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> h_C;
h_C.resize(IMG_WIDTH * IMG_HEIGHT);
...
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(d_C, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * IMG_WIDTH * IMG_HEIGHT, h_C.data());
```